# Scheduled pages report from AEM

Tags: aem

Is there any way to view a report for all pages scheduled for activate later from AEM? I am able to see one report under Tools (Workflow Report) which shows the total count of "Scheduled Page/Asset Activation", but I want to see all page information about scheduled page activations including time for activation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view all running workflow instances by navigating to 
http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/workflow/content/console.html and clicking on the the `Instances` tab. Look for `Scheduled Page/Asset Activation` under the `Workflow Model` column. You can group and sort by that column.

If you want to search from within your code, you can find the resources waiting to be activated with these JCR-SQL2 or XPATH queries:

```
SELECT * FROM [cq:Workflow] AS s WHERE ISDESCENDANTNODE(s,'/etc/workflow/instances') AND s.[modelId] = '/etc/workflow/models/scheduled_activation/jcr:content/model' AND s.[status] = 'RUNNING'

/jcr:root/etc/workflow/instances//*[@modelId='/etc/workflow/models/scheduled_activation/jcr:content/model' and @status='RUNNING']
```

However, it sounds like what you want to do is create a custom report:

1. Navigate to http://localhost:4502/miscadmin.
2. Open Reports in the left pane.
3. Click `New...` > `New Page...` in the right pane.
4. Select the `Workflow Instance Report` template and give it a title.
5. Open the new page.
6. Drag `Model` from the sidekick into the parsys. The report should immediately populate.
7. Drag `Payload` from the sidekick into the title bar where `Model` already exists.
8. Click the dropdown arrow in the `Model` column, select `Filter`, `equals` and enter `Scheduled Page/Asset Activation`.
9. Drag `Status` from the sidekick into the title bar where `Model` and `Payload` already exist.
10. Click the dropdown arrow in the `Status` column, select `Filter`, `equals` and enter `RUNNING`.

You can drop in any other columns that you wish. You can save the report and set it up to create snapshots as well.

This will give you a report of pages scheduled to be activated. Unfortunately, it won't tell you the time that the page will be activated. In order to accomplish this you will have to create a new reporting column component.

1. Copy `/libs/cq/reporting/components/instancereport/payloadcol` into your apps folder renaming as something like `scheduledcol`.
2. Look at the `scheduledcol` node and notice the `jcr:primaryType`, `componentGroup` and `sling:resourceSuperType`; it's a regular CQ component.
3. Update the `jcr:title` property to `Scheduled`.
4. Update the `scheduledcol/definitions/queryBuilder` node's `property` property. You can go with either `./data/metaData/comment` which gives you plain text or you can use `./data/metaData/absoluteTime` which gives you the date and time in milliseconds when the activation will occur. Look at a workflow instance under `/etc/workflow/instances/<date>/model_<number>/data/metaData` and you'll see how the new component's queryBuilder property matches up.
5. Return to your report, refresh the page, and drag the new `Scheduled` component from the Sidekick onto your report.

Comment: Thanks @nateyolles, it works :) however can you please explain how the schdulecol displaying the schduletime of the page.